# Не могу подключить базу данных SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Мне необходимо создать базу данных SQL на локальном компьютере. Я использую сервер Denwer. Потратил весь сегодняшний день, для того чтобы создать и подключить базу данных к своему локальному сайту. Почему у меня ничего не работает? (Если что, я просто привёл такой пример якобы табло вылета рейсов из аэропорта Домодедово).[image: Скриншот страницы]

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('domodedovo', 'domodedovo', '');
mysql_select_db('departures', $connection);
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `table`');
if (!$result) {
    echo 'OSHIBKA!';
}
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['flight'].'-'.$row['point'].'-';
?>
```

Comment: 1) Вставляйте текст сообщений, а не картинки. 2) Проблема в вашем коде. Очевидно, вы не проверяете ошибки, которые могут возвращать функции `mysql_*`. Почитайте руководство по их использованию и приведите ваш код. Пока в вашем вопросе смысла и информации для ответа - ноль.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Я нашёл ошибку:

> 1) Таблица "Table" находилась не в "Departures", потому что я случайно там напутал
>
> 2) У пользователя "Domodedovo" отключился доступ к базе данных (по неизвестной причине)

В обще могу сказать так - В коде ошибки нет! Это у меня произошла ошибка в базе данных.

Comment: Нет, ошибка у вас в коде. Причём **принципиальная ошибка**: отсутствие проверок на ошибки и вывода сообщений о них. Не было бы этой ошибки - не пришлось бы столько времени тратить на решение такие примитивной и простейшей проблемы.

Answer (score 3):

Ошибки кто за вас проверять будет?

```
$connection = mysql_connect('domodedovo', 'domodedovo', '');
if( !connection ) die(mysql_error());
if( !mysql_select_db('departures', $connection) ) die(mysql_error());
```

Только не забывайте потом читать что вам пишут в сообщениях об этих самых ошибках.